# Find the quotient of a polynomial division, in a given point

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, divisibility

Given $P(x)=99(x^{101}-1)-101(x^{99}-1)$,  find $Q(1)$ where $Q$ is the quotient of the division between $P(x)$ and $(x-1)^3$.

Obviously I could just divide the polynomials but that is not the solution I want. It is possible to figure out $Q(1)$ without doing long division, and that is the answer I am interested in.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on the question, actually. $P(x)=(x-1)^3Q(x)+R(x)$ where $R(x)$ is quadratic. To obtain $Q(1)$ differentiate each side three times with respect to $x$. $R$ vanishes and the derivatives of $Q$ get multiplied by zero when you put $x=1$. But is this what is intended?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we write:
$$ P(x) = (x-1)^3Q(x)+ax^2+bx+c$$
then 
$$P'''(x) =6Q(x)+(x-1)[......]$$
On the other hand we have
$$P'''(x)= 99\cdot 101 (100\cdot 99x^{98}-98\cdot 97x^{96})$$
So $$ 6Q(1) = P'''(1) = 99\cdot 101 (100\cdot 99-98\cdot 97)$$